# bulk insert from mysql to ms access table not working

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm developing software where I have to insert bulk data from a MySQL database to a MS Access database. I found some code on google but one line is causing problems...

How to write an sql insert query for ms access to insert data from mysql table.

What to put in Access sql query and as I have list of items to insert into access table or is there any way to put query to fill all mysql table records into access table so what it should be.... with above code it only insert same record if i put query as `insert into approved (id, word, ap proveds) values (0, 'fahad', 'no')`
Is there any way to form this query properly to work or put into a listbox. 
Index with loop for every item...... and below this line

```
 Dim table As New DataTable
    pth = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath

    Dim sourceConnection As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=fhdspl;password=az2352;port=3306;database=awami_spellchecker;Character Set=utf8;SslMode=none;")
    Dim selectCommand As New MySqlCommand("select * from approved", sourceConnection)
    Dim destinationConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & pth & "\database.mdb; User Id=admin; Password=;")
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


    Dim insertCommand As New OleDbCommand("
INSERT INTO approved ( 
  id, 
  word, 
  approveds) 
values (0, 'FAHAD', 'no')
", destinationConnection)
```

'''''''WHAT SQL QUERY SHOULD BE PUT HERE

```
    'Add parameters to insertCommand here, e.g.
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Integer, 10, "id")
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@word", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, "word")
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@approveds", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, "approveds")

        Dim sourceAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter With {.SelectCommand = selectCommand,
                                                    .AcceptChangesDuringFill = False}
        Dim destinationAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter With {.InsertCommand = insertCommand}

        sourceAdapter.Fill(table)
        destinationAdapter.Update(table)


    MsgBox("data copied successfull")
```

which is  called as

```
 insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Integer, 10, "id")
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@word", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, "word")
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@approveds", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, "approveds")
```

What should I change to make this work properly ..... or can anybody suggest me any other bulk insert code from mysql to access

Comment: And what on Earth has this got to do with PHP?  Don't use irrelevant tags.

Comment: i also used such method but its slow